# How to set position absolute to a specific div element when there is a lot of positioned nested elements

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I have the following html :

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="reference" class="group">
    <h1 class="resizeme">hello world</h1>
    <div class="resizeme">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    <p class="resizeme" style="background:red;">hello there I am another text</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

with the following css

```
      .resizeme{
            background: gray;
            padding: 6px;
        }

        body{
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #reference{
            background: orange;

        }

        .group:before,
        .group:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
        } 
        .group:after {
            clear: both;
        }
        .group {
            zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
        }
```

This is how it looks like (**PLEASE NOTICE HOW THE RED PARAGRAPH 'at the bottom' IS POSITIONED INSIDE THE GRAY DIV**):

http://jsfiddle.net/mody5/f30s81yv/1/

Using jQuery I would like to set div#reference to position:relative; and all other HTML inside #reference to `position:absolute` relatively to that #reference

I tried this (but it breaks the design) :

```
$("#reference").css("position", "relative");
$("#reference *").css("position", "absolute");
```

and I tried this one (which break also the design):

```
$('#reference *').appendTo('#reference');
```

How I can solve that ?

Comment: Easy, you unwrap them so they are no longer nested ?

Comment: `$('#reference *').appendTo('#reference')`

Comment: @adeneo how I can combine that to get the previous position then add `position:absolute` to those DIVs so they still like I didn't touch them

Comment: I don't know if you can do this while the divs are all children of each other and while each div has `position`. You may need to have all the divs be direct descendants of `<div id="reference">`.

Comment: @TylerH I updated my question! do you think I can move all element inside #reference and positioned each one without breaking the design ?

Comment: @medBo You definitely can. You might need to adjust it after you apply the `position` though. Do you want "Hello World" to remain visible?

Comment: @TylerH I would like my initial design to still the same after apply positioning, please see my jsfiddle above (exactly notice the red paragraphe at the bottom within the gray div) then apply the js lines (in my question above) to that jsfiddle, you will see how the red paragraphe loose their positioning

Comment: @medBo See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 // javascript variable should be declared on top.
 var $ref = $("#reference"); // for performance benifits http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-fasterjquery

 //single line
 $ref.css("position", "relative");
 var $allNestedElements = $ref.find("*");
 $allNestedElements.css("position", "absolute"); // for performance benifits http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-fasterjquery
```

```css
.resizeme {
  background: gray;
  padding: 6px;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#reference {
  background: orange;
}
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  zoom: 1;
  /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="reference" class="group">
  <h1 class="resizeme">hello world</h1>
  <div class="resizeme">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    <p class="resizeme" style="background:red;">hello there I am another text</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to maintain the layout. "Hello World" and the orange background are both not displaying in your Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use CSS? Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f30s81yv/4/) that does it in CSS and has the same layout:

```css
.resizeme {
    background: gray;
    padding: 6px;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#reference {
    position: relative;
    background: orange;
}
.group:before, .group:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
}
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1;
    /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

#reference > .resizeme {
    position: absolute; /* This line gives the children of #reference absolute positioning */
}

#reference > h1.resizeme {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 21px;
    padding: 6px 0px;
}

#reference > h1.resizeme:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -21px;
    height: 21px;
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
}

#reference > h1.resizeme:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: -21px;
    height: 21px;
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
}

#reference > div.resizeme {
    top: 92px !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="reference" class="group">
    <h1 class="resizeme">hello world</h1>
    <div class="resizeme">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <p class="resizeme" style="background:red;">hello there I am another text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, no jQuery/JavaScript needed with this approach.

Comment: unfortunately I need to use jQuery because the initial css files are not written by me, so I need to convert all things dynamically

Comment: @medBo you can't add new CSS files? This really isn't a good candidate for JavaScript.